# how to play http live streaming video URL in jwplayer on my https website?

Tags: http, video, https, jwplayer, mixed-content

I am newb for [jwplayer](https://www.jwplayer.com/). 
I have issue to play http live streaming video URL on my https website.

I have following live streaming video URL

> http://xyz.3da92.cdn.net/803DA92/abcd/v/RA/abcdxyz/play.m3u8?xyz

and my website like https://example.com with has [jwplayer](https://www.jwplayer.com/).

but when I have try to play live streaming
I am getting following:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://example.com' was loaded over HTTPS,
```

I am not able to change live streaming video URL becuse it is third party URL So, I can't control it. And want to run my website on https.

So, My question is how to play http live streaming video URL on my https website?

Comment: Did you manage to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Proxy the stream on your server to output https.